# как добавить configuration file в Андроид?

Tags: java, android, google-api

Я реализую возможность подключения к приложению через Google SingIn. Иду строго по документации

вот ссылка

```
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating?hl=ru
```

и вот дошел до пункта

Add the configuration file to your project

в нем написано "Скопируйте google-services.json file , который вы только что загрузили into the app/ or mobile/ в дерикторию вашего студио проекта", и далее описывается команда которую нужно ввести в терминале

```
$ mv path-to-download/google-services.json app/
```

Но 1-е я не копировал никакие файлы себе в проект, а во вторых команда которую нужно ввести в терминале показывает такую ошибку

```
aleksey@aleksey:~$ mv FromGitHub/google-services.json app/
mv: cannot stat ‘FromGitHub/google-services.json’: No such file or directory
aleksey@aleksey:~$
```

пишет, что нет такого файла. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы [предыдущий](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config) пункт читали?
Там есть кнопочка для получения google-services.json, у меня она правда сейчас почему то не работает, бесконечная крутилка показывается. Но получаемый по ней файлик и нужно кинуть в /app